# Should have + past participle

Tags: modal-verbs

> I should have been sentenced to prison , but my lawyer convinced the court that I'm innocent

The person who said the sentence is thankful because he is not in prison now , he does not wish to be in prison .

My question is:  could we use "should have +pp" to mean that something was to expected but it didn't happen (and we are happy because it didn't happen) ?

Comment: I should leave now. I should have left then. The reasons can only be imagined by others if not revealed.

Comment: Though I am an English learner, I know that we may also be unhappy because something didn't happen. For example: "she should have arrived by now, but she hasn't".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is: could we use "should have +pp" to mean that something
>   was to expected but it didn't happen (and we are happy because it
>   didn't happen) ?

Yes, here you are talking about what was expected, but it did not happen.

```
He shouldn't have come to work with that flu, but here he is!
Amazon should have accepted the return, but they only offered me a 10% coupon.
```

Also, I can use the same structure to talk about my expectations:

```
It shouldn't rain today, there's not a cloud in the sky!
```

There are other cases

More examples: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/should